# How to save variable for every user in dash to use it in callback initialization?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, dashboard

I'm trying to build dashboard that can dynamically update my model and I'm trying to make it multiuser, so users can concurrently see different models
So far I used dcc.Store(storage_type='session') inside my code,
but I don't know how to make variables for every user that i can "unpack" inside callback initiation if i need dynamic number of graphics for every user that depends on number of features
so I need a way to do something like this

```
@app.callback(Output('graph','children'),
              [Input('object_{}'.format(i), 'value') for i in range(<var_for_user>)])
...
```

what should i user instead of 'var_for_user'?

Comment: I think this would be considered anti-pattern for Dash. It's stateless by design, so each user's session isn't related to others, but you're specifically trying to undo that. You'd have to store the value outside of Dash somewhere, like a DB, but maybe Dash isn't the right tool for this problem if you need to break one of its core features in order to use it.

Comment: maybe i put it wrong. this var is different for every user, its more like user's configuration

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense. What you want is probably `pattern matching callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks). You could still use the `dcc.Store` to hold the variable, and use that when building the graphics with the pattern-matching approach.